# How do I create visually lossless images from videos using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-11

How do I create visually lossless images from videos where the differences are so undetectable that you won't notice even if you zoom in, all by using FFmpeg?

I have the following types of videos:

1. H.264 with YUV 4:2:0 to 4:4:4, and bit depth from 8bit to 16bit.
2. H.265 with YUV 4:2:0 to 4:4:4, and bit depth from 8bit to 16bit.

I have tried the usual command line for extract images for each of these types of videos but I keep getting the wrong colors.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf format=rgb24 output%05d.jpg
```

Comment: One reason for lossy images is to conserve space. I have not seen what you want but if you do find something, the size of your images will balloon

Comment: The video files are likely compressed, but if you want to get an image from the video that looks identical to a frame of the video I suggest converting it to a PNG of the same resolution as the video. PNG is lossless compression and JPEG is lossy.

Comment: Please be more specific, and show what you have tried. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). You have posted a question about [Extracting HDR Dim Pictures](https://superuser.com/questions/1834171/extracting-hdr-dim-pictures). It's a bit problematic that you are asking a more general question, without mentioning the "dim pictures issue".